# What does the term "implementation dependencies" mean?

Tags: java, dependencies, terminology

From wikipedia:

> Java is a general-purpose computer-programming language that is concurrent, class-based, object-oriented, and specifically designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible.

What exactly does "implementation dependencies" mean? Are they talking about implementations of Java runtimes maybe?

Comment: I would say yes (depending on what you mean by Java runtimes) since the next sentence after your quote states *"It is intended to let application developers "write once, run anywhere" (WORA), meaning that compiled Java code can run on all platforms that support Java without the need for recompilation."* - [Java Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))

Comment: @JonnyHenly "JRE" is an abbreviation for "Java Runtime Environment". There's OpenJDK. There's Oracle's JRE. It's what runs Java bytecode. Right?

Comment: It means you install the JRE and it just "just works", without requiring 900 different C++ redistributables.

Comment: @Michael But then how is the language's design related to the implementation of the runtime?

Comment: The language was designed to have all runtimes behave *almost* exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation dependencies** are usually compared to **Interface dependencies**

These definitions are quoted from "**Variability in Software Systems
The Key to Software Reuse**" by **Jilles van Gurp**

**Implementation dependencies** : The references used in the relations between components are typed using concrete classes or abstract classes.

**Interface dependencies**: The references used in the relations between components are typed using only interfaces. This means that in principle the component's implementation can be changed (as long as the required interfaces are preserved). It also means that any component using a component with interface X can use any other component implementing X

Hope that helps !

Comment: So let's focus on **"The references used in the relations between components are typed ..."** *References* as in "a reference to a java object"? What are *components*? What are *typed* references? It says "the relations", so what are *relations*? How do we use those "typed references" to "relate" "components"?